# How to split a string in java using (,) with certain conditions

Tags: java, regex, string

I know we can split the string in java using `split()` method of `String` class but my scenario is, I have a string like

> Mega ,Bytes, "house No. 201, ABC Street, Pune, India", 23, Student

When I am spliting the string using `row.split(",")` 
 The output is

> Mega
>  Bytes
>  "house No. 201
>  ABC Street
>  Pune
>   India"
> 23
> Student

I want "house No. 201, ABC Street, Pune, India" as a single string. Please suggest how can I do this. One way to do this take splitted string array elements and concatenate them into single string. but the fields inside  two double qoute("") the fields may differ, sometimes 3 or 4 fields combination. So how can I do this. Please suggest the way to do this

Comment: do matching instead of splitting `"[^"]*"|[^,]+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, is `matches()` method?

Comment: no, use Pattern and Matcher classes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, it is not duplicate question, yes there are so many questions for splitting and I gone through it also, but this criteria was not defined

Comment: it should be `"[^"]*"|[^,"]+`